# How to specify placeholders for date_select in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, formtastic

I have haml that uses formtastic to specify date_select input (year,month,day):

```
  = f.input :birthday,
    start_year: 1900,
    end_year: time.now.year-18,
    input_html: { class: 'select2' }
```

Which renders me 3 select boxes with parent element class as a placeholder:

```
<select ... placeholder=".span1">
```

How to specify placeholders? Year;Month;Day would be good enough.

Comment: what does `:placeholder => 'test_placeholder'` in input_html hash do?

Comment: unfortunately - nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Formtastic Documentation](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic/blob/master/lib/formtastic/inputs/base/timeish.rb):

`<%= f.input :publish_at, :as => :date_select, :labels => { :year => "Year", :month => "Month", :day => "Day" }  %>`

**[Edit]**

If `formtastic-bootstrap` gem is used, you probably need to use `:placeholder` as it is used on the [code](https://github.com/mjbellantoni/formtastic-bootstrap/blob/master/lib/formtastic-bootstrap/inputs/base/timeish.rb#L43).
Though, on [master](https://github.com/mjbellantoni/formtastic-bootstrap/blob/master/lib/formtastic-bootstrap/inputs/base/timeish.rb#L52) the `:placeholder` option is not implemented, with a TODO comment instead.

Comment: I guess formtastic-bootstrap gem is overriding something. Somehow it does not work. Anyway - direction is right, somehow missed that piece of documentation.

Comment: @ArnisL. I didn't know you were using `formtastic-boostrap`. You could be right on that case... On [formtastic-bootstrap code](https://github.com/mjbellantoni/formtastic-bootstrap/blob/master/lib/formtastic-bootstrap/inputs/base/timeish.rb#L51) it seems you should use `:placeholder`. But there's a todo on `:placeholder`, and a comment saying it's useless right now.

Comment: ok, so then it's clear now. thing doesn't work at the moment. thank you for your time :)